# Saber si una función sigue en ejecución o ya termino de ejecutarse en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto, base64

Tengo una función que me pasa las imágenes que tengo en la Base de datos a *base64*, pero como son muchas imágenes la ejecuto luego  que el documento carga, lo que quisiera saber es si ¿hay forma de saber si aún esta recorriendo el array esa función o si ya se termino de ejecutar? y adicional pase las imágenes a *base64* para que carguen al toque, pero no se si esta mal que lo hice.
Si tienen algo mejor escucho ideas, acá dejo el pedacito de código.

```
function toDataURL(src, callback){
    var image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
 
    image.onload = function(){
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
      canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      callback(dataURL);
    };
    image.src = src;
  }





lang-js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < data_consult_productos.length; i++) {
        toDataURL('../../reme/productos_clientes/' + data_consult_productos[i].imguno, function(dataURL) {
            data_consult_productos[i].imguno = dataURL;
        })
        toDataURL('../../reme/productos_clientes/' + data_consult_productos[i].imgdos, function(dataURL) {
            data_consult_productos[i].imgdos = dataURL;
        })
        toDataURL('../../reme/productos_clientes/' + data_consult_productos[i].imgtres, function(dataURL) {
            data_consult_productos[i].imgtres = dataURL;
        })
        toDataURL('../../reme/productos_clientes/' + data_consult_productos[i].imgcuatro, function(dataURL) {
            data_consult_productos[i].imgcuatro = dataURL;
        })
        toDataURL('../../reme/productos_clientes/' + data_consult_productos[i].imgcinco, function(dataURL) {
            data_consult_productos[i].imgcinco = dataURL;
        })
    }
  
    for (let i = 0; i < data_consult_inmuebles_imagenes.length; i++) {
        toDataURL('../../reme/inmuebles_clientes/' + data_consult_inmuebles_imagenes[i].img, function(dataURL) {
            data_consult_inmuebles_imagenes[i].img = dataURL;
        })
    }
  
    for (let i = 0; i < data_consult_vehiculos_imagenes.length; i++) {
        toDataURL('../../reme/vehiculos_clientes/' + data_consult_vehiculos_imagenes[i].img, function(dataURL) {
            data_consult_vehiculos_imagenes[i].img = dataURL;
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Puedes colocar la función toDataURL ??

Comment: Listo ya la coloque amigo pero eso no me funciona bien, lo que estoy evaluando es para ver la carga del  window.addEventListener("load", function()

Comment: Entiendo que no es ahí el problema, pero es para tener una visión de lo que estas haciendo

Comment: ah oka chévere igual soy nuevo en esto así que cualquier consejo es bien recibido

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar una variable externa que te diga si la función terminó o no, así:

```js
termino = false

async function funcionLarga() {
    termino = false

    // Código que toma mucho tiempo
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000))

    termino = true
}

function verificar(){
    if (termino)
        console.log("La función terminó")
    else
        console.log("La función no terminó")
}

console.log("Ejecutando función")

funcionLarga()

verificar()

setTimeout(verificar, 3000)
```

O si necesitas que suceda algo al terminar  de ejecutarse, puedes usar un `Promise`:

```js
console.log("Ejecutando función")

prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Código que toma mucho tiempo

    rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
    console.log(rng)
    if (rng == 1) resolve()
    else reject()
})

prom.then(() => console.log("La función terminó correctamente") , () => console.log("La función no terminó correctamente"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi parecer es muy ineficiente como lo estás haciendo

Según lo que entendí, tú quieres:

- Ir viendo cuando se carga cada imagen y cuando se completó la carga
- Poner las imágenes en base64
- Y además, yo lo sumaría, mejorar la performance del asunto

Creo que tengo una solución a esto, es algo complicada porque ocupa muchas [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Tu deberás ajustarlas a tu escenario

```js
const imagenes = [
    "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-WFK2YfHFXOk/XQU7oD_cptI/AAAAAAAAXho/vwoHHil_AIcerulq1lfwke8PXgk9PjRDQCLcBGAs/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/Robotech%2B8.jpg",
    "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cK9n71ycqBg/XQU8ChVbBII/AAAAAAAAXiI/Oll-1_IUtAM0HX1m9yZwRKtxr-ue17yFQCLcBGAs/s1600/Robotech%2B17.jpg"
];

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    CargarImagenes(
        imagenes,
        function (base4,index) {
            console.log(base4);
            console.log(index);
        },
        function () {
            console.log("completado");
        }
    );
});
    

async function CargarImagenes(array,tick,complete) {
    let index = 0;
    for (let i of array) {
        GetImageBase64(i,index).then((r) => {
            tick(r.Base64,r.index);
            if (r.index == imagenes.length - 1) {
                complete();
            }
        });
        index++;
    } 
}

async function GetImageBase64(url,index)
{
    let blob = await fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.blob();
        })
        .then(function (blob) {
            return blob;
        });

        return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve({ Base64: reader.result, index: index });
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        });
}
```

Empecemos desde abajo hacia arriba

- GetImageBase64 le ingresas una url de la imagen y un número que vendría siendo el index del array. Te retorna un objeto, el cual tiene 2 propiedades:

  - Base64: Es la imagen en base 64
  - index: Es el mismo index que ingresaste por parámetro
- CargarImagenes recibe un array de url y 2 funciones. La primera función se ejecuta cada vez que una imagen es cargada y la segunda cuando todas las imágenes han sido cargadas
- window.addEventListener Aquí iniciamos la carga y pasamos los 3 parámetros a la función anterior.

Con esto podrías incluso implementar un progress bar

Update:

Te dejo, una variante que podría servir a tu caso partícular:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    CargarImagenes(
        data_consult_productos,
        ['imguno','imgdos','imgtres','imgcuatro','imgcinco'],
        function (base4,index,prop) {
             data_consult_productos[index][prop]=base4
        },
        function () { }
    );

    CargarImagenes(
        data_consult_inmuebles_imagenes,
        ['img'],
        function (base4,index,prop) {
             data_consult_productos[index][prop]=base4
        },
        function () { }
    );

    //etc
});
    

async function CargarImagenes(array,propiedades,tick,complete) {
    let index = 1;
    let max = array.length * propiedades.length;
    for (let i of array) {
        for (let p of propiedades) {
            GetImageBase64(i[p],index,p).then((r) => {
                tick(r.Base64,r.index,r.prop);
                if (r.index == max) {
                    complete();
                }
            });
            console.log(index + 100);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
async function GetImageBase64(url,index,p)
{
    let blob = await fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.blob();
        })
        .then(function (blob) {
            return blob;
        });

        return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve({ Base64: reader.result, index: index, prop:p });
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        });
}
```